# Gradle Error: Execution failed for task ':XY:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug' java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-play-services

I've updated Android Studio from version like 1.1 to latest 2.2 and since then, I can no longer launch my application from Android studio. Which sucks!

When trying to run it on device, I get this gradle error (XY is the main project module)

> Gradle Error: Execution failed for task
>   ':XY:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'. >
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.google.android.maps.MapController

What is interesting, if I just "make" the project that means not running it, gradle finishes it task without complains. Also, Android studio doesn't show any error in the files where i am using com.google.android.maps.MapController like missing class etc.

And as I said, this appeared after I upgraded Android studio and that kind of sucks, if code stops working due upgrading of IDE! So now I have to either fix it, or again downgrade the IDE!

Please tell me, what could be the problem!

Btw this is the snippet of top level gradle file (build.gradle)

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
    classpath "com.newrelic.agent.android:agent-gradle-plugin:5.+"
}
```

Before i updated the AS the gradle line was like this:

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
```

But new AS complained this is the old gradle version and forced to use 2.2.0, maybe the error is related to newer gradle version?

Also, i was thinking, that changing the line below in same file to either newer or older version could fix it, but i don't know which are the other options (simply i don't know from head what i could write there another and there is no selections of version)

```
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
```

Btw, this is the snippet of gradle of main module XY:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0'
    ...
```

Anyone knows what is the problem? Please help, thanks.

Comment: 1) Disable Instant Run 2) Your Google Play Services are very outdated 3) You don't have the Google maps dependency, providing is that included in location?

Comment: The latest is [`com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0`](https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/), by the way

Comment: Hi Cricket, you want submit it as answer? Disabling instant run worked, any reason why IR doesn't work? Because the services are old? And, how can i find out which versions i can type next to "compile" or "classpath" gradle statements? Thx

Comment: I have no idea why it'd work. As for the versions, click that link, look at the versions. Everything that Gradle downloads is on bintray jcenter. You could also search here for other repositories http://mvnrepository.com, or read the latest documentation for each library you're using

Comment: ok, thank you for helping me with the problem.